# Do you think I should apply a transformation to my independent variables?

Tags: multiple-regression, r-squared

I have done a simple linear regression on my two standardized independent variables and standardized dpendent variable. In the residual plot there is a distinct quadratic pattern left after the two explanatory variables have done their work. I feel like applying a quadratic transformation to my independents, in order to add the R squared of the residual quadratic pattern to the R squared of the model. What should I do exactly to achieve this?

[image: residual plot]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You have a pretty clear indication of spread related to predicted value (what a pity that this package - is that SPSS? - standardized the predicted value, obscuring any chance of seeing if perhaps spread was near-proportional to mean). There are several alternatives to transformation you should perhaps consider as well. What does your response measure? Is it inherently positive?

Comment: Very clever Glen :), yes the response measures prices. (This is SPSS for clarity). In fact a logarithmic transform of price corrects its logarithmic distribution. But after that, the independents no longer (need to) explain that logarithmic distributed response. That's what I can't seem to achieve: add that remaining quadratic model to the existing multiple (2 variables) model. I tried a square root on the independents, squaring them.. Good idea to show a plot of non-standardized predicted values. hang on.

Comment: You have a clear bias problem near zero there, so it's still more obscure than I hoped. Still, I'll try an answer shortly

Comment: When you say that the independents are no longer needed to explain the log-response, what are you looking at to conclude that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are two things going on:

1. The response is not linear in the predictors (or at least not in some important predictors).
2. The spread increases as the mean increases, perhaps in proportion to the mean.

There are several things that might be done.

a) you might consider something like a GLM; the most obvious first model to try would be a gamma GLM with log-link, but you might try an identity link and some quadratic terms.

b) you might try some monotonic transformation of $y$. The obvious one to try is the log transformation.

c) another possible transformation that's sometimes suitable with a single predictor, or where the heteroskedasticity is mainly related to a single predictor is to divide $y$ by $x$ and regress it on $x$. This makes some sense when the conditional response is close to symmetric.

d) you could add quadratic terms in your predictors (you wouldn't just square them, you'd keep the linear terms as well; though you might want to consider orthogonal polynomials). However, this would completely fail to deal with the heteroskedasticity. If you're mostly interested in testing, ne possibility would be to use some form of [heteroskedasticity consistent standard errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity-consistent_standard_errors) (/sandwich estimator), but the heteroskedasticity that's present is very simple in form, and it seems like overkill to use something with so many implicit variance parameters.

It's important to have a reasonable model for the conditional distribution (especially the mean and variance, though as noted in (d), something might be done in the case of variance); if you don't, the inferences you seek to make will not have the properties you want.